# Grails: Same page but changing _theTemplate with webflow

Tags: templates, grails

I am fairly new to web development, new to Grails, and would love some help.  I want to know if it is possible to have a Grails webflow that doesn't actually change the page as the state changes, but instead changes a template within the page.  Is this possible?  If so, can you help point me to a tutorial, or give me some advice and very basic code samples of how to pull it off?  Even just pointing me to a tutorial somewhere else (I couldn't find one) would be a great help.

Thanks a ton,
Me

Answer (score 0):

To update just a template of the page you'll have to use AJAX. The [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#ajax) has basic examples of the tags that support it.

I think that `<g:remoteLink>` and `<g:formRemote>` will do just fine for a fast and easy approach.

And remember that on the server side (controller), you use the [render method](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) to update a template.

Depending on what you need to do, I think I can update the answer to provide a rough example